# Django and HTML5 Video - source tags are gone on Safari

Tags: javascript, django, html, safari

I'm working with Django and I have a template like this:

```
{% load formatting_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<div class="utility-modal utility-modal__medium modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-content--header">
            <h4 class="modal-content--header--title">{{ education_modal_title }}</h4>
            <button class="modal-content--header--action icon-close" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content--body">
            <video width="100%" controls="true" autoplay poster="{% static poster_url %}" id="video1">
              <source src="{% static video_ogg_url %}" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora, vorbis">
              <source src="{% static video_url %}" type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2">
              <source src="{% static video_webm_url %}" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8, vorbis">
              <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content--footer">
            <button onclick="document.location='{{ button_page_link }}'" class="btn btn__primary btn__block">Go to page</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The video urls are passed as variables from the view. This works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari. On Safari, the three source tags inside the video are simply gone.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple known bugs about it.

Essentially, this HTML5 sends data as chunks instead of a full HTTP request which will include a byte-range header that describes the video.

Safari doesn't support chunks, requires the byte-range headers. and Currently Django doesn't support byte-range headers.  The workaround is to host the videos on Apache or NGINX which supports the byte-range header, and have you link the src to the other site instead of local on the Django.

Here's the bug.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22479 
https://github.com/jooby-project/jooby/issues/523